# Search results scrape not providing a CSV in the output - Python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv, urllib

I have the below script that seems to run correctly in a colab notebook.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse, parse_qs
from lxml.html import fromstring
from requests import get
import csv
import cssselect

def scrape():
    with open('searches.txt') as searches:
        for search in searches:
           userQuery = search
           raw = get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + userQuery).text
           page = fromstring(raw)
           links = page.cssselect('.r a')
           csvfile = 'data.csv'
           for row in links:
               raw_url = row.get('href')
               title = row.text_content()
               if raw_url.startswith("/url?"):
                   url = parse_qs(urlparse(raw_url).query)['q']
                   csvRow = [userQuery, url[0], title]
                   with open(csvfile, 'a') as data:
                       writer = csv.writer(data)
                       writer.writerow(csvRow)

scrape()
```

However I am not getting a CSV file when executing. Any reason why?

Comment: did you try creating an empty `data.csv` file before executing?

Comment: Have you tried `print(csvRow)`, to assert that everything is working right up until writing it to disk?

Comment: @kelyen, why is it important to ensure the file is created before-hand? Opening a file for appending that doesn't exist _creates_ it, [docs: open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: it sets aside permission problems on your system if it works by doing that

Comment: @ZachYoung I did and also used the method of creating an empty df prior to the function. The output is completely blank which leads me to believe the data is not being written to the csv. Any thoughts?